# Dihedral Group of Order 12 in Cycle Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, geometry, dihedral-groups

[image]

I want to check that this cycle notation is correct for the Dihedral Group of order $12$. I found this graph in Wikipedia. I did not find the cycle notation. May you please tell me if my cycle notation is correct?

Here is my solution: I will name the vertices $1,2,3,4,5,6$ in the clockwise direction.

***1) Rotation 0 degrees***

$(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)$

***2) Rotation 60 degrees (clockwise direction)***

$(123456)$

***3) Rotation 120 degrees***

$(135)(246)$

***4) Rotation 180 degrees***

$(14)(25)(36)$

***5) Rotation 240 degrees***

$(153)(264)$

***6) Rotation 300 degrees***

$(165432)$

***7) Flip 2-5***

$(2)(5)(13)(46)$

***8) Flip 1-4***

$(1)(4)(26)(35)$

***9) Flip 3-6***

$(3)(6)(15)(24)$

***10) Flip A***

$(12)(36)(45)$

***11) Flip B***

$(14)(23)(56)$

***12) Flip C***

$(16)(25)(34)$

Comment: Whatever you're asking, you should delete all the 1-cycles. They can be omitted.

Comment: @hellotinfish The 1-cycle notation is important for the Polya's enumeration theorem and the Cauchy-Frobenius-Burnside theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a computationally easier way to do this, and you do not even need to revisit the geometric intepretation of $\operatorname{Dih}(6)$. Let $\phi:\operatorname{Dih}(6)\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\rightarrow\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the group action of the dihedral group of a regular hexagon on the six vertices. Let $\varphi:\operatorname{Dih}(6)\rightarrow\operatorname{Sym}(6)$ be the permutation representation afforded by the action. Then write $\varphi(r)=(123456)$ and $\varphi(s)=(13)(46)$. Then since $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, and $\operatorname{Dih}(6)=\{1,r,r^2,\dots,s,sr,sr^2\dots\}$ is generated by $r$ and $s$, you can compute the cycle representation of each element of $\operatorname{Dih}(6)$, e.g. $\varphi(sr^2)=\varphi(s)\varphi(r)^2=(13)(46)(123456)^2=\dots$ (check it yourself :D).

**P.S.** Hmm... it seems that your answer is correct, but you should check it again using the group action approach anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Very interesting!

Comment: The 1-cycle notation is important for the Polya's enumeration theorem and the Cauchy-Frobenius-Burnside theorem.